# Converting a pandas df to json without {}

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm currently working with a pandas Dataframe with a few hundred rows:

| amount | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Banana |
| 5 | Apple |
| 10.5 | Strawberry |
| 3 | Apple |

I'm now converting this to a son File using:

```
data = data.to_json('Fruits.json', orient='records')
```

Now the output is:

```
[{ amount : 2 , fruits : Banana }, { amount : 5 , fruits : Apple }, { amount : 10.5 , fruits : Strawberry }, { amount : 3 , fruits : Apple }]
```

Now the thing is that for moving forward I need the json to look like this:

```
[{ amount : 2 , fruits : Banana ,amount : 5 , fruits : Apple , amount : 10.5 , fruits : Strawberry , amount : 3 , fruits : Apple }]
```

Is there a pandas integrated orient suffix to do this or has anyone got an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Python dictionaries must have unique keys.  In your expected output you have keys of fruit and amount many times.  This doesn't make python sense.

Comment: Your output is not a valid JSON object either...

Comment: @QuangHoang from reading the spec, unique names are actually optional. It's up to the JSON interpreter to decide: "The names within an object SHOULD be unique ... some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4

Answer (score 1):

As per comments

1. your requested output has issues - duplicate keys and curly braces are part of standard
2. you can deal with duplicate keys by summing first
3. transpose then generate JSON gets close to what you want

```
df.groupby("fruits").sum().T.to_dict(orient="records")[0]
```

#### output

```
{'Apple': 8.0, 'Banana': 2.0, 'Strawberry': 10.5}
```